# Autocompletion work only with search results web part pages

Tags: web-part, search-results

I have an auto completion script in jQuery that work fine only in a pages that contains the search results web part but not in the other pages, why does this happen and how can I resolve the problem?
there is the script

```
 var myresult;
     var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
 var results;   
      $.ajax({
            url: url+"/_api/web/siteusers", 
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {

        results = data.d.results;
        for( j in results){
                myresult[j] = results[j].Title;
            }


        }
        });

    $( "#SearchBox input" ).autocomplete({
                source: myresult 

                    });
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it is very hard to tell why it is working in a specific matter

Comment: this no code solution, it's only done with adding the web parts by configration in the Sharepoint site

Comment: You say you have a jQuery auto-complete script, that must be code right?

Comment: oh yeah sorry i forgot it, i note that the result of ajax is showing in the console, i note also that if i execute this code in the console the autocmplete work fine in this page